# Preciso abrir o primeiro link de uma pesquisa no youtube em uma Webview

Tags: java, javafx, webview, youtube, webengine

O webview não ficará visível, então o objetivo é abrir automaticamente o primeiro vídeo da pesquisa. Acredito que não é muito complicando em JS.

código:

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private WebView tela;

    @FXML
    private Button botão;

    WebEngine webengine;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        webengine = tela.getEngine();

        webengine.load("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=exemplo");
    }
```

Comment: Essa função retorna o link: document.getElementsByClassName('yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-video-renderer')[0].getAttribute('href'). Mas por algum motivo ela dá erro ao ser executada dentro do JavaFX. O getElementById só pega se for apenas 1 elemento.

Comment: Pelo que pesquisei, o mais prático seria usar um código em JS